# How to use ItemGrabResult in QML JS?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm trying to render a Qt Quick Item tree to an offscreen container so I can read raw pixels:

```
Rectangle {
    x: 20
    y: 20
    width: 20
    height: 20
    color: 'red'

    Rectangle {
        x: 5
        y: 10
        width: 5
        height: 5
        color: 'green'
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        grabToImage(function(result) {
            console.log('Grab result:', result.image)
        })
    }
}
```

prints:

> qml: Grab result: QVariant(QImage, QImage(QSize(20, 20),format=QImage::Format_RGBA8888_Premultiplied,depth=32,devicePixelRatio=1,bytesPerLine=80,sizeInBytes=1600))

However I don't know how to access that QImage in JS.

I tried:

```
for(var k in result.image)
    console.log(k)
```

(prints nothing)

```
console.log(Object.keys(result.image))
```

(prints `[]`)

```
console.log(result.image.format)
```

(prints `undefined`)

```
image.source = result.url
```

where `image` is the `id` of an existing `Image` item in the scene. This one works, but then the problem becomes how to read the pixels from the `Image`. I know I can use a `Canvas` to draw the image and then use `ctx.getImageData(...)` to get the pixels. It looks quite a long way to a simple goal. Is it the only way?

Comment: As I know there is no way to manipulate pixels of image in QML, I think it just goes beyond the concept. You have to use some C++ item/plugin to do that. The callback argument is [ItemGrabResult](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-itemgrabresult.html) that has [image](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-itemgrabresult.html#image-prop) property that holds the pixel results but what in fact to do with it is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution going `Item.grabToImage()` -> `Image` -> `Canvas` -> `CanvasImageData`:

```
function copyFromItem(item) {
    item.grabToImage(function(result) {
        tmpImage.source = result.url
    })
}

function copyFromImageData(im) {
    // read RGBA bytes in im.data[...]...
}

Image {
    id: tmpImage
    visible: false
    onSourceChanged: tmpCanvas.requestPaint()
}

Canvas {
    id: tmpCanvas
    visible: false
    width: ...
    height: ...
    onPaint: {
        var ctx = getContext('2d')
        ctx.reset()
        ctx.drawImage(tmpImage, 0, 0)
        copyFromImageData(ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 10, 10))
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I read RGBA bytes in im.data[...]...?

Comment: it's an array of R, G, B, A byte values in row-major order

Comment: Can you correct your answer as a working version?